# Is there any possibility to do work both 32bit and 64bit MS office Add-in from single installer in Wix C#?

Tags: c#, wix, 32bit-64bit, excel-addins

I am working on WIX to make an installer for Excel Add-in, can make two installers each for 32bit and 64bit. But need to make a single installer to work both 32bit and 64bit excel add-in when I install.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Installer technology does not support an MSI that targets both x86 and x64. One way to accomplish this is to use the WiX Bundle containing both x86 and x64 installations. You then define and build three artifacts: the x86 msi, the x64  msi and the bundle.

The Platform attribute of the Package element indicates the target platform: 
https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/